# Rails nesting from the CoreController. Troubles with routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have some user types such as Student, Teacher, Admin. For each user type I have a controller. For instance student controllers placed in the `app/controllers/students` directory. But mostly controllers are the same. Because of this I created **core controllers** placed in the `app/controllers/core`.

**app/controllers/core/settings_controller.rb**

```
class Core::SettingsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    # instance variables, redirections etc. placed here...
    #
  end

  # other actions...
  #
end
```

**app/controllers/student/settings_controller.rb**

```
class Student::SettingsController < Core::SettingsController

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :student do
  # ...
  resource :schedule, :only => [:show]
  resource :settings, :only => [:show, :update]
end

namespace :admin do
  # ...
  resource :settings, :only => [:show, :update]
end
```

Problems started when I added `<%= link_to "<", schedule_path(:date => @date.prev_month)" %>` to my `views/core/settings/_month_nav.html.erb` file.

Is there any solution except writing this ugly peaces of code:

```
<% if admin? %>
  <%= link_to "<", admin_schedule_path ... %>
<% elsif student? %> 
  <%= link_to "<", student_schedule_path ... %>
...
```

Comment: It sounds like you aren't using STI - if not then you could consider it as an option as it seems tailor-made for your requirements and would probably allow you to have one controller for everything.  [Here's a Rails 4 tutorial about STI](http://thibaultdenizet.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/).

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
<%= link_to "<", self.send("#{current_user.class.to_s.downcase}_schedule_path",:date => @date.prev_month) %>
```

I used `current_user` because I am not sure how you are setting this as your view code was not very clear.